# Form for one model in view for another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing a simple rails app and I currently have 2 models, Location User, that have the same relationship to the Message model.  That is, Location has many messages, User has many messages, and Message belongs to User and Location.  I am currently trying to add a form to create a new message on my Location show view.  Here is some code:

```
app/views/locations/show.html.erb:

<h1><%= @locaton.name %></h1>
<p><%= @location.location %></p>
<p><%= @location.discription %></p>
<%= link_to "Find a Different Location", crags_path %>

<h2> Messages
<ul>
    <% @location.messages.each do |message|%>
    </li>
        <h3><%=message.user.username%></h3>
        <p><%=message.content%></p>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Locations Controller:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @locations = Location.all
end

def show
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @Location = Location.new
end

def create
    @location = Location.new(
        name: params[:location][:name],
        location: params[:location][:location],
        discription: params[:location][:discription])
    @location.save
    flash.notice = "#{@location.name} Created!"
    redirect_to location_path(@crag)
end

def edit
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    @location.update_attributes(params[:location])

    flash.notice = "#{@location.name} Updated!"

    redirect_to crag_path(@location)
end

def destroy
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    @location.destroy
    flash.notice = "#{@location.name} deleted."
    redirect_to locations_path
end

end
```

MessagesController

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

def new
    @message = Message.new
end

  def create
    @message = current_user.messages.build(
                          content: params[:message][:content])
    redirect_to crags_path                   
  end

end
```

Form partial that I am trying to include in location/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label "Leave a Message" %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
</p>
<%= f.submit "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

When I try to include the partial i get the following error

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

and I assume that the form is trying to communicate with the locations controller since it is in a locations view, and since it cant find the instance @message in the locations controller, it doesn't know what to do.  I am trying to figure out how to include this form from messages controller in the view for locations.  If i create a view for new_message_path it works fine, again, I am guessing because it is functioning within the message views so it referes back to the messages controller.

I also was wondering if there was any way to creat a message that is linked to both current_user and to the location where the form is (or hopefully will be when I figure out the last problem.  A message object has a location_id attribute, how do I use the page that I am currently on (with url /locations/location_id) to link the message to that location?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'll need to actually set the `@message` variable to a new message in the controller:

```
# locations_controller.rb
def show
  @location = Location.find(params[:id])
  @message = @location.messages.build(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Using `@location.messages.build` will automatically populate the `location_id` with `@location.id` for the new message, and we're setting the `user_id` here too.

With that in place, you should be able to build the form in your page (although you might need to add some hidden fields to store the `user_id` and `location_id` for `@message`).

With that done, you can trim down your `messages_controller` too. Unless you want to have an additional page to create a new message not tied to a location, you can probably get rid of your `new` action (and route). Then you can simplify your `create` action to:

```
# messages_controller.rb
def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
  if @message.save
    # whatever you want to do on successful save, for example:
    flash[:success] = "Message created."
    redirect_to location_path(@message.location_id)
  else
    # whatever you want to do if saving fails
  end
end
```

Comment: None of that is tested, so you may hit a few speedbumps along the way, but that should get you headed in the right direction :)

Comment: One thing that is still not working is that the hidden fields for location_id and user_id are not showing up in the params hash, they both look like `<% f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id%>`

Comment: since they are not showing up on params, i cant assign them in the Message controller when i create the message, any idea how to get around this?

Comment: They should already be set on `@message`, so have you tried just using `<% f.hidden_field :user_id %>` (and `location_id`) without setting the value? I'd inspect the HTML of the form itself to make sure everything is set properly there too.

Comment: I see why they are already set in the instance message that we created in the locations show action, but how do they get set when we call the create action in the messages controller where we are calling `@message = Message.new(params[:message])` hence creating a new instance... maybe i am missing something...

Comment: All the properties should all get passed through in `params[:message]`, although it sounds like that's not happening. Have you looked at the HTML of the form in the page?